# How to write i hat and j jat from keyboard in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mathematica

I want to ask linear algebra question on reddit but i couldn't find any techniques to write special mathematical notation such as i hat and j hat via keyboard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inserting a math equation to a LibreOffice presentation](https://askubuntu.com/q/859923)

Answer (score 0):

In this [educational resource](https://www.webassign.net/manual/instructor_guide/r_i_letter_forms.htm) there is a complete list of symbols arranged in alphabetical order.

The simplest way I have found to use them is to copy and paste from the resource.

Comment: But certain symbols cannot copy such as j-hat

Answer (score 0):

**Try using the keyboard layout of a language that actually uses hats**, like French, for example (hats are called *accents circonflexes*).

Check the steps here https://askubuntu.com/a/1030433/1066357 on how to add and select a language, and assign a keyboard shortcut to switch keyboard layout. You can add any variant of French.

Then you just have to switch to French layout using the settings or the keyboard shortcut, type **^** (the key immediately to the right of P, see below) then **j**.

[image: French keyboard layout]